# Proof of non-existence simple graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How can we prove the non-existence of any simple graph with 12 vertices and 28 edges, while at the same time degree of all vertices is 3 or 6?

Comment: The number of edges is half the sum of the degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that for every graph $G=(V,E)$, we have:
$$
\sum_{v \in V(G)} deg(v)=2*e
$$
Where $e$ is the number of edges.

Now, for sake of contradiction suppose that there exists a graph with 28 edges, in which every vertex have degree 3 or 6. By the above theorem we have:
$$
\sum_{v \in V(G)} deg(v)=2*28
$$
The right side of this equality is divisible by 3, but the left side is not. A contradiction. So such graph doesn't exist.